# How add custom AuthorizeAttribute for some specific Controller use code on MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

The general case we just put the Attribute **on the Contoller top**. like:

```
[Authorize]
public class XXController : Controller
{

}
```

But because My project need use the third part binary DLL. **we don't have the source code** for change the original controller on the binary dll, but we can ignore the default authorize use some setting for it, then I just want to know Is there possible to add custom Authorize Attribute to for the XXController **use code**?

This is my CustomAuthorizeAttribute:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
        public bool IsOnlyAdminAccess {get ;set;}

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (Session.IsAdmin && !IsOnlyAdminAccess )
            {
                  // redirect 
            }
         }
}
```

So now I think Is there **Maybe** on global.aspx. use some way like(**just idea**) add the CustomAuthorizeAttribute for the specific Controller:

```
AddCustomAttributeWayOrMethod(XXController, new CustomAuthorizeAttribute(IsOnlyAdminAccess = true));
```

Some friend maybe said I just add it to `GlobalFilterCollection` , like:

```
GlobalFilterCollection.Add(new CustomAuthorizeAttribute ());
```

But I **already** add it for global controller.   I just need my XXController use **IsOnlyAdminAccess = true** property, other controller all don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would create a subclass of the original controller and put my attribute over the child class.

```
 // this is the other controller in a dll, you don't have the source code
 public controller TheirController {

 // and this is yours, you have it in your code
 // with your custom attribute
 [CustomAttribute]
 public controller YourController : TheirController {

    // all actions are inherited
```

Comment: Can I use this way override the original Controller and Actions?